# Extract indexes from multi-hot vector in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to extract indexes from multi-hot tensor in Tensorflow?

For examples,

```
a = (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Then, output should be

```
output = (0, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean this

```
a = tf.Variable(initial_value = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
print( sess.run( tf.where(tf.equal(a, tf.constant(1)) )))
```

then the output is this.

> [[0]
>     [1]
>     [3]]

Comment: and then you just have to reshape it to obtain the desired form : tf.reshape(output, (-1,1))